# Returning json response at differne depths with hibernate and spring

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

I have two different use cases that require different json responses.

I have omitted some of the hibernate/spring stuff for brevity.

```
public class Parent {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Child child;

    ...

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="child") 
    public getChild() {
        return this.child;
    }

   ...

}
```

The first use case requires only `id` and `name`. This will work with the above code.

```
@RequestMapping("/parents")
@ResponseBody
public List<Parents> getParents() {
    return parentService.listAll();
}
```

The second use case required `id` and `name` and `child`.  The only way I was able to get around this was to remove the `@JsonIgnore` annotation and modify my hibernate query.

`from Parent` to `from Parent p join fetch p.child c`

However, by doing this, now my first query will also select child elements and I don't want this because the first statement might return 1000+ rows and I don't want the overhead of also returning all the child object data.  I can't use a different query either for the first case `from Parent p` because when jackson tries to serialize it will throw a lazy initialization exception for the child object as the `@JsonIgnore` is now removed.

Is there a way using spring and hibernate to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the @JsonFilter annotation to define a specific filter on each of your entity bean. Then, define in your Spring app configuration a custom ObjectMapper in which you'll be able to specify the attributes that you want to (de)serialize to/from JSON for each of your JSON filters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the domain model (Parent/Child) is not necessarily a good candidate to be sent over the wire, and this is one of the common reasons (the whole data is not always needed), another reason are for example model circular references that prevent serialization.

This can be solved by creating a separate [view model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_model) specific to each use case with only the needed fields, and convert that to JSON instead.

One example of a library that helps automate the mapping between domain model and view model is [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).